# Switching to full screen does not stretch horizontal linear layout

Tags: android

This example is straight from Android Studio > New Project wizard > "Fullscreen Activity". To that, I have just added some buttons in a Horizontal Linear Layout.

All layouts are set to match parent for width. The question is, why don't the buttons resize/realign/re-space and fit the entire width of screen in fullscreen mode?

[image]
[image]
[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#0099cc"
    tools:context=".FullscreenActivity">

    <!-- The primary full-screen view. This can be replaced with whatever view
         is needed to present your content, e.g. VideoView, SurfaceView,
         TextureView, etc. -->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/fullscreen_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:keepScreenOn="true"
        android:text="@string/dummy_content"
        android:textColor="#33b5e5"
        android:textSize="50sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <!-- This FrameLayout insets its children based on system windows using
         android:fitsSystemWindows. -->
    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button4"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Button" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Button" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Button" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Button" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/fullscreen_content_controls"
            style="?metaButtonBarStyle"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
            android:background="@color/black_overlay"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            tools:ignore="UselessParent">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/dummy_button"
                style="?metaButtonBarButtonStyle"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="@string/dummy_button" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </FrameLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

I found your question interesting. I played around a little and found that these changes will fix the issue. I'm not completely sure why this fix works, but it does...

In FullScreenActivity, make this change:

private final Runnable mHidePart2Runnable = new Runnable() {
    @SuppressLint("InlinedApi")
    @Override
    public void run() {
      // Delayed removal of status and navigation bar

```
  // Note that some of these constants are new as of API 16 (Jelly Bean)
  // and API 19 (KitKat). It is safe to use them, as they are inlined
  // at compile-time and do nothing on earlier devices.
  mContentView.setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LOW_PROFILE
          | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    /*      | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
          | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY
          | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
          | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION);*/
}
```

};